# Why errno is not set to EDOM even sqrt takes out of domain arguement?

Tags: c, errno

errno is not being set to EDOM for domain error of sqrt() function in    windows 
It shows correctly on Linux but failed on windows (Using GCC 7.4) ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
double val;

errno = 0;
val = sqrt(-10);

if(errno == EDOM) {
printf("Invalid value \n");
} else {
printf("Valid value\n");
} 

errno = 0;
val = sqrt(10);

if(errno == EDOM) {
printf("Invalid value\n");
} else {
printf("Valid value\n");
}

return(0);
}
```

Expected result : Invalid value
                      Valid value
Actual result : Valid value
                    Valid value

Comment: You really don't want floating-point math functions to set `errno`. It's a bad idea and only kept for compatibility with legacy crap. Without it, code generation for modern architectures is much nicer, since the compiler can just use the `sqrt` instruction of the underlying hardware (causing the somewhat more sane ieee754 exception flag to be set on invalid operands), whereas it needs to emit extra code to set `errno` (which no sane programmer will use), so there is a compiler flag `-fno-math-errno` to get sane behavior.

Answer (score 8):

The math functions are not required to set `errno`.  They *might*, but they don't have to.  See [section 7.12.1 of the C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.1).  Theoretically you can inspect the value of the global constant `math_errhandling` to find out whether they will, but that's not fully reliable on any implementation I know of, and may not even be defined (it's a macro, so you can at least use `#ifdef` to check for it).

Instead, you can check whether the input is negative before calling `sqrt`, or (if your implementation properly supports IEEE 754 in detail) you can check whether the output is NaN (using `isnan`) afterward.

Answer (score 4):

As @zwol observed, the Standard allows implementations some latitude with respect to how (and whether) the math functions signal errors.  In particular:

> On a domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined
>   value; if the integer expression `math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO` is
>   nonzero, the integer expression `errno` acquires the value `EDOM`; if the
>   integer expression `math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT` is nonzero, the
>   ''invalid'' floating-point exception is raised.

([C11, paragraph 7.12.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.1p2))

Upon a domain error in `sqrt`,

- On Linux with [glibc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt), `NaN` is returned, `errno` is set to `EDOM`, and a floating-point exception is raised.
- On Windows with recent MS runtime library, an indefinite NaN is returned, and a floating-point exception is raised, maybe ([the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sqrt-sqrtf-sqrtl?view=vs-2019) are a bit unclear to me, but definitely some kind of status flag is set that you can subsequently evaluate via the `_matherr()` function).  There is no mention of setting `errno`.