# Which functions are affected by -fno-math-errno?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, errno, math-functions

I have been excited by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57674631/2492801 and I consider using `-fno-math-errno`. But I would like to be sure that I do not harm the behaviour of the software I am working on.

Therefore I have checked the (rather large) codebase to see where `errno` is being used and I wanted to decide whether these usages interfere with `-fno-math-errno`. But how to do that? The documentation says:

> -fno-math-errno
>
> Do not set errno after calling math functions that are executed with a single instruction, e.g., sqrt...

But how can I know which math functions are executed with a single instruction? Is this documented somewhere? Where?

It seems as if the codebase I use relies on `errno` especially when calling `strtol` and when working with streams. I guess that `strtol` is not executed with a single instruction. Is it considered to be a math function at all? How can I be sure?

Comment: Your first goto for stuff like this should be [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: @NathanOliver I have checked it. I could not find any hint whether `strtol` is executed with a single instruction or whether it is considered to be a math function. Also I could not find a list of math functions that are executed with a single instruction. Could you give me more hints what you mean?

Comment: We can't know the implementation generally so you actually have to check your implementation.  What you can do though is use it to get a list of functions that do set `errorno`.  Also, `strtol` uses integer math, not floating point math so it is exempt.

Comment: The second part of your comment seems correct. The quotation from the gcc documentation in my post is below a line stating: "The following options control compiler behavior regarding floating-point arithmetic." Therefore `strtol` is safe. But the first two sentences I do not understand. For all functions from `<cmath>` that I have checked, cppreference states: "Errors are reported as specified in math_errhandling." But still I do not know whether they are executed with a single instruction. So what is your recommendation? Read the implementation source code?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler -- this is non-conforming behavior, so documentation of what the standard requires (e.g., cppreference) won't help you. You're stuck with whatever documentation your compiler gives you.

Comment: @PeteBecker And since the gcc documentation seems not to contain a list of affected methods, I cannot know? Hmmm... what a pity!

Comment: Note that (in C at least), math functions only set errno if `(math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO) != 0` -- if that config bit is 0, they might or might not set errno in case of a range or domain error.  So as long as gcc arranges for it not to be set, `-fno-math-errno` is still standards conforming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find list of functions affected by `-fno-math-errno` in GCC's [builtins.def](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.def) (search for "ERRNO"). It seems that only some functions from `math.h` header (`cos`, `sin`, `exp`, etc.) are affected. Treatment of other standard functions that use errno (`strtol`, etc.) will not change under this flag.

Comment: The querent here seems not to know the standard meaning of "math function", and is asking if `strtol` is a math function.  You're only answering that part by example, so maybe good to state more clearly that math functions are ones declared in `math.h` which take `float` or `double`, or `long double` args.  i.e. they do floating point calculations and nothing else.  Things like `nextafter`, `nearbyint`, and `lrint` are also math functions, not just stuff like `cos` and `exp` which are FP implementations of continuous mathematical functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, I've updated the answer. In case you think that more details may be helpful - feel free to update the answer.