# sse2 instruction set not enabled

Tags: g++, sse

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O3 -c -Wall
DFLAGS=-g -Wall
LDFLAGS= -lz -lm -lpthread

KSWSOURCE=ksw.c
ALGNSOURCES=main.cpp aligner.cpp graph.cpp  readfl.cpp hash.cpp form.cpp btree.cpp conLSH.cpp
INDSOURCES=whash.cpp genhash.cpp formh.cpp conLSH.cpp

INDOBJECTS=$(INDSOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(KSWSOURCE:.c=.o)
ALGNOBJECTS=$(ALGNSOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(KSWSOURCE:.c=.o)

INDEXER=conLSH-indexer
ALIGNER=conLSH-aligner

all: $(INDSOURCES) $(ALGNSOURCES) $(KSWSOURCE) $(ALIGNER) $(INDEXER)

$(ALIGNER): $(ALGNOBJECTS)
        $(CC)  $(ALGNOBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(INDEXER): $(INDOBJECTS)
        $(CC)  $(INDOBJECTS) readfl.o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

debug:
        $(CC) $(DFLAGS) $(ALGNSOURCES) $(KSWSOURCE) $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o $(ALIGNER) $(INDEXER) a.out
```

I have the above makefile but I am getting an error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/include/emmintrin.h:31:3: error: #error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
 # error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
```

From what I understand and googled this is a flag for parallel computation.

I tried from other posts with the same problem to either include:

```
CXXFLAGS=-03 -c Wall -mfpmath=sse
```

OR:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")
```

but without any success. Can you help?

I am not sure a CXX flags is necessary because a lot of (probably) cascading errors are shown in ksw like,

```
ksw.c:49:2: error: ‘__m128i’ does not name a type
  __m128i *qp, *H0, *H1, *E, *Hmax;
```

Comment: Are you using a pure (handwritten) Makefile, or cmake? Are you in 32 or 64 bit mode? Does your CPU actually support SSE2 (check `cat /proc/cpuinfo`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-msse2` is the specific option, so passing that to GCC will work, if you get your build scripts set up to actually do that.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options

Or better, use `-march=native` to enable everything your CPU has, if you're building for local use, not for distributing a binary that might have to work on an old-but-not-ancient CPU.  (Of course, if you care about performance, it's weird to be building for 32-bit mode.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.  Unless your CPU is too old to support SSE2, e.g. a Pentium III.  Or for example, there are embedded x86 CPUs without SSE, like [AMD Geode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geode_(processor)).  In that case, a binary built (successfully) with `-msse2` will probably crash with an illegal instruction on such a CPU.)

`-mfpmath=sse` just tells GCC to use SSE for scalar FP math assuming that SSE is available; unrelated to telling GCC to assume the target CPU *does* support SSE2.  It can be good to use it *as well* for performance, but it's not going to matter in getting your code to compile.

And yes, SSE1/2 intrinsic types like `__m128i` will only get defined when SSE is enabled, so `error: ‘__m128i’ does not name a type` is a clear sign that `-msse` wasn't enabled

---

If using autoconf or something, maybe use this:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -fno-math-errno"
```

If you have .c files as well as .cpp, set CFLAGS as well as CPPFLAGS.  More options like `-flto` can be helpful for optimization (cross-file inlining at link time), if you get those added to your LD options. As well as any other optimization options like `-ffast-math` if you want to use it.  Or at least `-fno-trapping-math` helps some, and GCC already did optimizations that violated the semantics trapping-math was supposed to provide.  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673825/how-to-force-gcc-to-assume-that-a-floating-point-expression-is-non-negative) re: `-fno-trapping-math -fno-math-errno` being safe to use basically everywhere, even in code that depends on strict FP like Kahan summation.

Comment: Adding -march=native indeed  fixed everything. All cascading errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me also:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-march=native"
```