# emmintrin.h:31:3: error: #error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled" # error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled", "scaling solution"

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake, sse

I have been building multiple projects that require sse2 instruction set. Adding `-march=native` as mentioned in [sse2 instruction set not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398128/sse2-instruction-set-not-enabled) has done the job till now.

However, in the 3 projects I have needed this, the gcc commands in the makefile were easy to locate and editing slightly the makefile worked. Now I tackle a far more complex makefile generated by cmake. I believe it makes more makefiles in other folders and then runs them etc. So just adding a simple `-march=native` is neither desirable nor easy and will take a considerable amount of time, if it is feasible afterall.

Is there a way to somehow always have sse2 enabled, opposite to now? I googled this but wasn't able to find something.

Given the fact that non of the makefiles I downloaded from github had `-march=native` inside, it leads me to believe that indeed there might be some way to set this on gcc/g++ level beforehand?

I found this -mfpmath=sse flag but was not able to formulate a correct gcc/g++ command (if that is related).

Can you help me?

Comment: Instead of editing the generated makefiles, you should add `-march=native` to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` file before generating the makefiles.

Comment: could you please give the exact code? If it works, also please provide  your answer as a separate answer so I can accept it.  To help you, CXX_FLAGS is not even set in the CMakeLists.txt for the moment

Comment: SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, i.e. a normal compile on a modern system (making a 64-bit executable) already includes `-msse2` on by default.  You only need it manually if you're building obsolete 32-bit binaries.  (Although you should still use `-march=native` if you're only going to run your binary on this computer, or newer ones like it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the compiler option `-march=native` in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
SET(PROJECT_FLAGS "-march=native")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${PROJECT_FLAGS }")
```

Or

```
add_compile_options(-march=native) # CMake 2.8.12 or newer
```

Comment: second proposition worked. First one not ( probably I added it in the wrong place in the file?) Anyways, thanks a lot Altaf, accepted answer.